# Regex add Characters after Sentence Mac Terminal

Tags: regex, macos, replace, sed

I'm trying to Add Characters to the end of certain lines of many text files. 
Sample of the Text (These are Subtitles)

```
WEBVTT

00:00.000 --> 00:03.000
Der perfekte Case sozusagen war,

00:03.000 --> 00:06.000
dass man in der gleichen Stadt wohnt, befreundet ist,

00:06.000 --> 00:08.000
sich 6 Monate nicht gesehen hat 

....
```

I need to add **L:90%** to the end of each Timecode. (with a space at the beginning)
I've come up with this Regex to mark the end of the correct lines, but I couldn't find out about the correct Syntax to add Stuff in the end.

```
(-->).*
```

Ive been using this:

```
sed -i '' 's/->/-->/g' */*.vtt
```

to find and replace through the terminal.

Thanks a lot!
Vinni

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
sed -i 'bak' -Ee 's/(--> [0-9:.]+)/\1 L:90%/' */*.vtt
```

The `\1` is a backreference to the stuff you captured inside the `()`. The `-E` flag enables extended regular expression support. Otherwise the capturing doesn't work as well.

Comment: the end needs to be `*.vtt `. I've edited the answer :)